# App_Code required for ASP.NET MVC 4 HtmlHelper Extension in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, html-helper

I've been spending the better part of two hours trying to figure this out.  Here goes:

I just want to create an HTMLHelper extension method.  This has been done many times before, and I know I'm coding it correctly.  However, Razor only seems to know about it if I place the code file within App_Code (a folder which I thought no longer had meaning in the MVC world!)

How do I know this?

Quite simply...I have two identically-coded HTMLHelper extension methods in two separate identically-named files.

The first file, placed inside ~/Extensions contains the extension method `DisplayForProperty`

The second file, placed inside ~/App_Code contains the extension method `DisplayForProperty2`

When in a view, I type `@Html.Displ`- Intellisense only shows me `DisplayForProperty2`!

I do not have a `@using` statement, as that does not appear to be necessary to see `DisplayForProperty2`.  Not to mention, it doesn't change anything in this case.

So, why is this?  Should this even be happening this way?  Is this just Razor being retarded, or am I the one being retarded?

I'm using a fully-updated copy of VS 2012.

PS - On another note, do I have to place the namespaces reference in every web.config under every /Views directory (as in, in every single Area), plus at the root?  Why can't I just put this in the root or in the root /Views directory?

Comment: Is this a web site "project"? If so, then try this using a web application project.

Comment: This project was started by using the ASP.NET Internet Application template in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: You can put the namespace reference in the Web.config at the root of your application, or (even better) in the Web.config at the root of your ~/Views/ folder alongside the default ones referenced by MVC. The configuration will be inherited by any subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to put the html helper extension methods inside of App_Code. While a little old, the tutorial on asp.net: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs guides you pretty well.

I typically have a "Helpers" folder under the root of the MVC project with separate class files for each. They're in the `Project.MVC.Helpers` namespace and I add a `@using Project.MVC.Helpers` to the Razor views I want to use the helper in.

Comment: OK.  This is exactly what I thought!  Can you explain the behavior I'm seeing, then?

Comment: Same way as I do it, just make a folder and add the following sentence to the web.config situated in the folder of the views or add a @using-statement <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Namespace.Of.Your.Helper" />
      </namespaces>

Answer (score 0):

The app_code folder is still a special folder which is automatically compiled and referenced by the project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the namespace that was generated on the HtmlHelper class when you put it in a folder outside of App_Code?

Perhaps all that you're missing out is the @using directive to point to that namespace inside your view.

Comment: Can you share the project folder so we can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the namespace that contains your helper to the Web.config file inside your views folder.

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Namespace.Of.Your.Helper" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This will allow your views to use your helper without a @using that references the namespace.